# Plants that can be carried around?

Tags: plant-recommendations

Right now I am transporting a potted avocado (just potted the seed) from one state to another, and I am finding that I really enjoy carrying around this pot with life growing in it. Are there any species of plants that would readily lend themselves to being grown entirely when one is walking around with them? I assume that such a plant would be hardy, have shallow roots, not be very picky with climate, and be able to fit in a small pot that could be held with one hand, can anyone suggest such suitable species of plants?

Comment: It's not the moving around it's the growing conditions where you are. If this time you have a basement apartment that is dark and next time a sunny place....

Comment: You mean like a fashion acessoire? Or like the Queen tends to be seen with a bouquet of flowers?

Comment: @kevinsky I suspect it's even more - not frequent moves, but the plant version of a lap dog...

Comment: This got out of hand quickly.. Cant a man just enjoy the company of a plant? :(

Comment: Sounds like a troll post to me, especially due to the added comment by @Loonuh

Comment: What you going to do with it when you're asleep? Nonsense question, no plant will like being touted about in anything from freezing weather to heated spaces. Rebutia miniscula might though, they cope with extremes of temperature, and good luck with that...

Comment: I would like to assure everyone that I am being serious, even if this sounds really silly or nonsensical

Comment: Small [catci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cactus) perhaps? +1 for original attitude.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest sempervivum tectorum (AKA Hens and Chicks, or Live Forever). It has shallow roots, is hardy, etc. You'll likely need to get some sun once in a while, though. It's an evergreen perennial that withstands frosts, cold, snow and heat well. Most people think it needs lots of sun, but it grows well in outdoor shade, too. It can even live quite a while without soil or water.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you really are serious, I'll post my comment as an answer - many plants are good in cold or hot temperatures. What they're not good at is switching between one and the other every few hours, so if, for instance, its a cold winter's day, and you carry your plant out and about with you, then go to an office or a home which is heated, and you do this on a continual basis, the transition shock to the plant is extreme. Or in reverse - extreme heat outdoors, air con set on cold indoors.

Therefore, about the only plant that might (and its only might) withstand this treatment for a period of time would be a desert type cactus - as it needs to be small, something like Rebutia miniscula.